# How to populate a textbox with an array index from the combobox selected index of a different array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, combobox

I have created two string arrays from a text file and populated a combobox with array1. What I would like to understand is, how do I get a textbox to show the index of array2 that matches the selected index of the combobox (array1)?

I thought something like this may work:

```
if(phoneComboBox.Text == cPhone[index])
{
    nameTextBox.Text = cName[index]; //show equal index item to cPhone/phoneComboBox
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried a foreach loop, maybe I'm just doing it wrong. I have the reading of the text file and arrays in the window_loaded event and don't know if that's the issue. I've seen SelectedIndexChanged event mentioned a lot in similar questions, but I do not have that event to use, just SelectionChanged.

Can someone please point me on the right track with this? I know arrays may not be the best use here, but they are what I have used, so please help me to understand it properly.

This is how I've read the arrays:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //read file on start
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    StreamReader custSR = new StreamReader(cFileName);
    line = custSR.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref cPhone, cPhone.Length + 1);
        cPhone[cPhone.Length - 1] = line;
        counter++;
        line = custSR.ReadLine();

        Array.Resize(ref cName, cName.Length + 1);
        cName[cName.Length - 1] = line;
        counter++;
        line = custSR.ReadLine();

        phoneComboBox.Items.Add(cPhone[cPhone.Length - 1]);
    }
    custSR.Close();

    /*string changeAll = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cPhone);
    string allOthers = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cName);

    MessageBox.Show(changeAll + allOthers);*/

    //focus when program starts
    phoneComboBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Show the code how are you populating the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the other answers, this is the answer I came up with that works. Fixes the indexOutOfRange exception I was getting.

```
private void phoneComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (phoneComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        nameTextBox.Text = cName[phoneComboBox.SelectedIndex]; 
    }
    else
    {
        nameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if you are comparing text strings, so you should use  the function ".Equals" in stead of
"=="

```
if(phoneComboBox.Text.Equals(cPhone[index]))
{
    nameTextBox.Text = cName[phoneComboBox.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: Still getting a blank textbox and removed the () from `SelectedIndex`

Comment: went with `if(phoneComboBox.Text != -1)` as that sorted the outOfRange exception I was getting from the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the condition, just get the selected index:

```
nameTextBox.Text = cName[phoneComboBox.SelectedIndex];
```

and in `WPF` you have [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

`SelectedIndexChanged` is for `winform`.

**Best Practice:**

But I would suggest you a better way to achieve this using [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You wont have to change a lot of code for it.

```
//Create "ComboBoxItem" instead of "array"
while (line != null)
{
    //initialize
    ComboBoxItem cmItem = new ComboBoxItem();

    //set Phone as Display Text
    cmItem.Content = line;  //it is the Display Text

    //get Name
    line = custSR.ReadLine();

    //set Tag property
    cmItem.Tag = line;  //it is the attached data to the object

    //add to "Items"
    phoneComboBox.Items.Add(ComboBoxItem);
}
```

and now its very simple to get the selected item in `SelectionChanged` event:

```
void phoneComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    nameTextBox.Content = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Tag;
}
```

You don't need to handle those arrays anymore.

Comment: That worked in the `SelectionChanged` event, but if i try to type a number different to the items in the combobox I get an indexOutOfRange exception. Oh well, another problem to figure out.

Comment: I have posted a better way to achieve it, please implement it you won't have any problem with that approach.

Comment: It has to be arrays, but thank you for the tips, I've found a way to make it work with help from here.